# Is there anyway I can mount a built in microwave oven like an over the range microwave?

Tags: microwave-oven

I am trying to mount a built in microwave/oven like an over the range microwave/oven. It won’t be over our range as we have a hood but I screwed up ordering cabinets and didn’t order the right ones for a built in. I order upper ones to mount a microwave underneath.

Comment: I would modify the cabinet and put the microwave in the cabinet, but if there is a spot notch or what ever just hang it there and not connect the range hood vents. Without a photo of the space we will be guessing.

Comment: I would think that a "built in" and "over the range" microwaves would have different mounting requirements that may or may not be adaptable. It might help if you included some pics of the microwave in question, showing the mounting assembly (and/or links to the documentation), as well as the cabinets in question. You may be able to simply frame out the cabinets to create a nook to install the built in into...

Comment: Built in microwaves usually have feet they stand on. Ones that hang under usually have a bracket at the back and screws through the top. So you probably need to invent some cabinetry/bracket magic or just swap for the right model.